# Does Magic 2015 For PC Change The Location Of The Multiplayer Chat Window?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015

One of my prior grievances with Magic 2014 for PC was that the chat window was placed in an awkward location (front and center) that obstructed view of the player's deck.  Has this changed in Magic 2015 for PC?  I didn't see this mentioned at all on forums or the developers web site. Multiplayer isn't available in the demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seem to be in the same place. My friend sent me the screen shot, and I don't know if you can move it.

[image: screenshot of the magic 2015 game]

Comment: It is in that place, and you can't move it. +1 for the screenshot.

Comment: It should be noted that you can hide it however by clicking the chat bubble again.